# How can I choice correct state in NFA

Tags: python, nfa

I have problem with NFA. I tried implement this but what if we have situation like on the picture with first loop - for example we can choice q0 or q1 if we start with 0 symbol;
[image]

```
def __init__(self, states, alphabet, transition_function, start_state, accept_states):
    self.states = states
    self.alphabet = alphabet
    self.transition_function = transition_function
    self.start_state = start_state
    self.accept_states = accept_states
    self.current_state = start_state
    return

def transition_to_state_with_input(self, input_value):
    if (self.current_state, input_value) not in self.transition_function.keys():
        self.current_state = None
        return
    self.current_state = self.transition_function[(self.current_state, input_value)]
    return

def in_accept_state(self):
    return self.current_state in accept_states

def go_to_initial_state(self):
    self.current_state = self.start_state
    self.list_of_state.append(self.current_state)
    print("\tactual state: " + self.current_state)
    return

def run_with_input_list(self, input_list):
    self.go_to_initial_state()
    for inp in input_list:
        self.transition_to_state_with_input(inp)
        print("\tinput symbol: " + inp)
        print("\tactual state: " + str(self.current_state))
        if self.current_state is not None:
            self.list_of_state.append(self.current_state)
        continue
    print(self.list_of_state)
    self.list_of_state.clear()
    return self.in_accept_state()

pass
```

Output:

```
INPUT: 112
    actual state: q0
    input symbol: 1
    actual state: ('q0', 'q2')
    input symbol: 1
    actual state: None
    input symbol: 2
    actual state: None
['q0', ('q0', 'q2')]
False
```

in this case our actual state should be q2 no list of states. How can I choice correct way?

Answer (score 1):

An NFA can be in more than one state at once.

You can correct this in your `__init__` with:

```
self.current_state = set([start_state])
```

and in `transition_to_state_with_input` consider each of the possible current states.

```
def transition_to_state_with_input(self, input_value):
    new_state = set()
    for state in self.current_state:
         # get the new possible states and add them to the new_state set
    self.current_state = new_state
```

This will also change in_accept_state with something like

```
def in_accept_state(self):
    return len(self.current_state & set(accept_states)) >= 1
```

Comment: what exactly mean get new state? how can i do that?

Comment: in the way you currently do it `self.transition_function[(self.current_state, input_value)]`

Comment: is it correct? I have only q0:     def transition_to_state_with_input(self, input_value):
        new_state = []
        for state in self.current_state:
            if (state, input_value) not in self.transition_function.keys():
                state = None
                return
            new_state = self.transition_function[(state, input_value)]
            return
            new_state.append(new_state)
        self.current_state = new_state